# How to make string as an Array Object in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have got below string values in a variable.

```
var mystring = '{"img_src":"/english/images/spa.jpg",
    "img_title":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet",
    "img_alt":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet",
    "img_height":"326",
    "img_width":"980",
    "header":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet",
    "subheader":"One of many groundbreaking amenities",
    "bg_color":"",
    "url_href":"1"}, 
     {"img_src":"/english/images/spa1.jpg",
    "img_title":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet",
    "img_alt":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet",
    "img_height":"326",
    "img_width":"980",
    "header":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet",
    "subheader":"One of many groundbreaking amenities",
    "bg_color":"",
    "url_href":"1"}'
```

Now I want to convert this string variable into Array object. So that If I try to access it my function it should behave like an array object. For example.

`some code to Convert(mystring) to an Array Object(myArryObject)`, then I want to pass it to my function like below

```
$.fn.liveBanner = function(myArryObject,optional_options) 
    { 
      //here I want to access my myArryObject as below
      alert(myArryObject[0].img_src) //then it should give "/english/images/spa.jpg"
});
```

Please suggest using JQuery.

**EDIT:**

I did the changes as suggested by @Deceze, please see below:

```
             var myString = "'"+ $("#RotationImages #mainHidden").attr("value")+"'";     

    var myArrayobj = jQuery.parseJSON('[' + myString + ']');
    alert(myArrayobj.img_src);
```

the above code is giving below error

```
Error: uncaught exception: Invalid JSON:'{"img_src":"/english/images/spa.jpg", "img_title":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet","img_alt":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet", "img_height":"326","img_width":"980","header":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet","subheader":"One of many groundbreaking amenities on the Flight","bg_color":"","url_href":"1"}'
```

Comment: Any reasons why it was given -1 to this question?

Comment: Any ideas how can I get it done, as its really very tricky!

Comment: Have you already tried to use $().data to store/retrieve the informations?

Comment: Please suggest some example, I have no idea of  $().data

Comment: Why you add "'" before and after the `$("#RotationImages #mainHidden").attr("value")` (see **EDIT:** part)? It seems the error. Moreover `alert(myArrayobj.img_src);` you should replace to `alert(myArrayobj[0].img_src);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make string as an Array Object in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768072/how-to-make-string-as-an-array-object-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your string only contains the objects inside the array, you have to add the array declaration before you parse it:

```
var myArrayobj = jQuery.parseJSON('[' + myString + ']');
```

Comment: I tried this code not working..its giving Error: uncaught exception: Invalid JSON:

Comment: @MKS: Why are you adding apostrophes around the string? Don't do that. Apostrophes (or quotation marks) are used around a literal string, they are not part of the string.

Comment: Which Apostrophes, I assume you know that what is in myString and that is what I need to make an array Object which can be further used in function as myArryObject[0].img_src

Comment: @MKS: The apostrophes in your code above: `var myString = "'"+ ...+"'";` You should not add those apostrophes around the objects.

Comment: Many Thanks to you all guys!, it fixed now

Comment: @MKS: If you want be polite you should vote up the answer which was helpful. The general rule described here (see  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask): "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer." It is easy for me to write this because I didn't wrote any answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given your `mystring` as defined, executing `var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON('[' + mystring } ']');` will result in an array of objects. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JWAx/) for a live example.

The reason you are getting the invalid JSON error is because you wrap your valid JSON in single quotes, thereby making it invalid. That is, the first line in:

```
var myString = "'"+ $("#RotationImages #mainHidden").attr("value")+"'";     

var myArrayobj = jQuery.parseJSON('[' + myString + ']');
alert(myArrayobj.img_src);
```

is invalidating your JSON. The first line should be (provided the value is correct):

```
var myString = $("#RotationImages #mainHidden").attr("value");
```

For more information on JSON see [json.org](http://json.org/) and [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627).

Answer (score -1):

Well, for a start, your inputs have the type="hidden" which means that no matter what jQuery you run on the surrounding div, these elements are never going to appear. If your bounding div has "display:none" then there's no reason to have the input type set to hidden.

You really need to revise the way you've written this code. You should have a stylesheet to hide the images (which you should place in the code as images) and then you can use the javascript to show them. You could use the jQuery UI Tabs demo as a guide how to properly structure the markup and then go from there.

Is there a specific reason you used inputs for the images?

Comment: Also, your code looks incomplete here. I think you're missing a lot of stuff. It seems like you are trying to change the img src on images that are not in the markup. I'd revise the whole thing if I were you.

Comment: Thanks Tady, please see my updated answer I am just one step behind to get my result, please see the updated JQuery part.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, your still not going in the right direction here.

Your jQuery has the following:

```
.attr('type','hidden').
```

This segment is setting the type to hidden. You're then writing the output to the screen.

Change this to:

```
.attr('type','image').
```

And see if that makes a difference (you will have to create an unset function where you change it back to "hidden" when you are done).

Like I say, this is really not the cleanest way to do what you are trying to do, but I can't point you any other way than to suggest you try again using a different method.

Comment: My Dear Friend it is not the problem with input type, I just want to store my all the ImageDetail in one variable which I will be using to add in my JQuery

Answer (score -1):

Finally I was able to write some JQuery which help me to resolve my problem, now I am able to get my desired HTML. Below is the JQuery code, please have a look and let me know for any improvement.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var rotationImagelength = $('#RotationImages input[type=hidden]').length; //Getting the length of the Rotation Image Input type hidder
        var ImageDetail; 
        var $addDetails="";
        var fromPageInput = $("<input>").attr("id", "mainHidden").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "fromPage").val(ImageDetail); //Generating the dynamic input type hidden  

        $('#RotationImages input[type=hidden]').each(function(index,element) //Loop for all the input type hidden in RotationImage DIV
        {   

            if(index != rotationImagelength - 1) //Loop for checking not the last input hidden, we are adding extra Comma(,)
            {                    
                ImageDetail = '{"img_src":"'+ $(element).attr("src")+'", "img_title":"'+ $(element).attr("title")+'","img_alt":"'+ $(element).attr("alt")+'", "img_height":"'+ $(element).attr("height")+'","img_width":"'+ $(element).attr("width")+'","header":"'+ $(element).attr("header")+'","subheader":"'+ $(element).attr("subheader")+'","bg_color":"'+ $(element).attr("color")+'","url_href":"'+ $(element).attr("href")+'"},';                                                  
                $addDetails += ImageDetail;
            }    
            else //Generating HTML for the last input hidden
            {
                ImageDetail = '{"img_src":"'+ $(element).attr("src")+'", "img_title":"'+ $(element).attr("title")+'","img_alt":"'+ $(element).attr("alt")+'", "img_height":"'+ $(element).attr("height")+'","img_width":"'+ $(element).attr("width")+'","header":"'+ $(element).attr("header")+'","subheader":"'+ $(element).attr("subheader")+'","bg_color":"'+ $(element).attr("color")+'","url_href":"'+ $(element).attr("href")+'"}';                                                            
                $addDetails += ImageDetail;
            }                

            $(fromPageInput).val($addDetails); //Adding full values in the dynamic input hidden created above    


        });
         $("#RotationImages").append($(fromPageInput)); //Appending to the RotationImage DIV so that we can easily use in JQuery.
         var test = ($("#RotationImages #mainHidden").attr("value"));
         alert(test);
});
```

Thanks for your help, your suggestion is always welcome

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a javascript var (I think):

```
gImgs = [
    {"img_src":"/english/images/spa.jpg",
    "img_title":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet",
    "img_alt":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet",
    "img_height":"326",
    "img_width":"980",
    "header":"Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet",
    "subheader":"One of many groundbreaking amenities",
    "bg_color":"",
    "url_href":"1"}
];
```

then

```
$('.slideshow').liveBanner(gImgs, {"autostart":false, 
  "pause_time":5500, "random":false});
```

So on each page you will have a different `gImgs`. Note that if you include a script for the `liveBanner` creation, you will have to define `gImgs` before the `<script src="..."></script>`, like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        <script type="application/x-javascript">
        <!--
            var gImgs = [ /* ... */ ];
        -->
        </script>
        <script type="application/x-javascript" src="yourscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many Thanks @RC did you saw my EDIT section in question, I am getting my required values in var test, my liveBanner function looks for an array     $.fn.liveBanner = function(images,optional_options) 
    { //so if you do alert(images[0].img_src) you get the first image src
}); I am surprised that why my above code is not working

Comment: My point is it's a bad idea to use dom as storage like you are trying to. Furthermore, your attr value will be text, not a JS object that's why it's not working

Comment: Can you please suggest what to do in this case, if I also tried to convert my string in javascript array, however still was not able to fix my problem.

Comment: I did, either use a JS var or serialize your object into your attr value (JSON ?)

Comment: can you please guide me little as I am confused with my code...appreciate your help, I am already using the JS var, please see var test to store my array values and then I am passing it into my function.

Comment: I'm confused with what you need direction for. If you value is "{foo: 1}" an `eval(yourValue)` will return a JS object with an attribute foo = 1

Comment: @RC if you see my question with heading Hardcoded JQuery with image1, is where I am giving hardcoded array section in it, now after that code written for #RotationImages where I am taking all the values from the input hidden inside #RotationImages and adding them in a newly created input hidden, then from that I am trying to pass its value to my function, but not working for me

Comment: @MKS, regarding to what I understand from your need (i.e. different image set on different page), I advised the use of a global var, that's all. If you question is why is my code not working then it's not well formulated and I advise you to reformulate (and post some link to `$.liveBanner()`)

Answer (score -1):

Try [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Comment: @MKS `var mystringObject = jQuery.parseJSON(mystring);` Read the documentation I linked to.

Comment: I tried using parseJSON, its giving below error: Error: JSON.parse
Source File: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
Line: 31..Please suggest what can be the reason..please see me updated question in EDIT section